# 6th gen intel processor compatible PSUs

Tags: cpu, power-supply

I'm planing to build a skylake desktop and I was wondering if I have to worry about getting a 6th gen intel processor compatible PSUs. I noticed some PSU advertise that they're "Engineered to support 6th generation and Skylake C6/C7 sleep states". Is this just marketing mumbo jumbo or does this have any merit?

Comment: Skylake CPUs support those power states.  If your PSU does not then your CPU cannot enter those power states.

Comment: It has merit, somewhat, as Ramhound stated, but it isn't necessary... few power supplies support it because it isn't essential, the processor and rest of the computer still work fine since most manufacturers disables those sleep states in BIOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it shouldn't cause a big issue, not having a Skylake approved PSU.

If not having low power states for the CPU isn't an issue for you, I wouldn't worry about it. I've done 2 PC builds around Skylake CPUs with "non Skylake approved" PSUs and they both work perfectly fine.